# How to add pagination for component front end (Joomla 3.4)

Tags: pagination, joomla3.4

I am new in `joomla`, i want to know how to `add pagination` to component for `FRONT END,` from searching i not found still for pagination in front end.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the guide here on official documentation, its for 1.5 but works great with 3.4 as well:
https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_JPagination_in_your_component#Implementing_Pagination_in_Front_End

Just three steps :) Next maybe you need to update the HTML structure for the pagination links generated by Joomla, you can do so by overrides and for that see this link:
https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Pagination_Links_Overrides